# Client did not send n bytes as expected

Tags: gwt, glassfish

We get this error:

```
[#|2009-08-12T11:38:31.803-0700|SEVERE|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-38080-3;_RequestID=8b3571bb-3c36-43f1-9e38-6947ca376436;|WebModule[]Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
javax.servlet.ServletException: Client did not send 142 bytes as expected
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsUtf8(RPCServletUtils.java:148)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.readContent(RemoteServiceServlet.java:335)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.doPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
```

very rarely and it is not reproducible. I have seen [posts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://tinyurl.com/5rqfp5&usg=AFQjCNF5OnO2JvH9lRAC_RkWpU4w8aQQBw) earlier but none of them justify the reason for it.

Appreciate if I can get some information:

1. Is it with some version of GWT or related software, will upgrading help?
2. How often you get this error?
3. Any more workaround?

Environment:
Client: ie 6
Server: GlassFish 2, GWT 1.5.3, Java 5

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not related to GWT: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3155. There's also someone there in the comments offering (private) help with this issue.